# Sending AJAX Request from HTML to ASPX

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax

I'm trying to send an AJAX request from a standard .html page to a .aspx page. I just want to see if this is something that can be done, but I keep getting 'Status Code: HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error'. I was told that aspx is not intended to work this way, but that it can be done.

My Javascript:

```
function handleload(e) {
            alert(req.responseText);
        }

        var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
        req.open('POST', 'helloworld.aspx' , true);
        req.addEventListener('error', function(e) {console.log(e)}, false);
        req.addEventListener('load', handleload, false);
        req.send();
```

My aspx Page:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true"
CodeFile="helloworld.aspx.cs" Inherits="helloworld" %>
```

My aspx.cs Page:

```
using System;

public partial class helloworld : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    public void Page_Load()
    {
        Response.ContentType = 'text/html';
        Response.Write("Hello World!")
        Response.End();
    }
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to do other than call another page?

Comment: I'm just trying to make it work, so I started with a simple Hello World test. It isn't really supposed to do anything other than return a string.

Answer (score 0):

> I was told that aspx is not intended to work this way, but that it can
>   be done.

While probably not the ideal way to make an AJAX call to a .NET stack, this is not true.

I recommend debugging your server-side code to see why it is throwing the 500 error.